# Symfony 2: JQuery Ajax, Gets 500 internal server error

Tags: jquery, symfony

I am using jquery ajax for a certain functionality like user clicks on the "Get Code" button , ajax request is made to one of the symfony2 controller action. When I try it am getting 500 internal error when i check the firebug console.

Here's the ajax code(Using FOSJsRoutingBundle):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var locale = '{{ app.request.get('_locale') }}';
    $('.codeBtn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: Routing.generate('gd_getcode',{ '_locale': locale}),
          success: function(html){
            alert("Successful Response from server");
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Here's my controller action:

```
public function getCodeAction()
{
    if ($this->container->get('request')->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $code = rand(1,9999);
        $this->getUser()->setAttribute('transactionCode', $code);

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject("Code")
                    ->setFrom('info@mymail.com')
                    ->setTo('mymail@email.com')
                    ->setBody($code);
                $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

        return true;

    }

}
```

Is anything wrong in my code or am i missing any of the ajax settings parameters.

Comment: Error 500 means any server-side problem that results in an absence of Response... You shoul debug it a tool like FireBug for Firefox, in the Console tab, you can check the error informations provided by Symfony exception handler...

Answer (score 0):

You can check Net>XHR panel of your firebug to find the request.
Expand the request and check the html tab to see what exactly is the response